# Is $3$ prime in the ring of integers of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> I am trying to determine if the number $3$ stays prime in the ring of integers of the quartic field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1})$, or rather adjoin a real root of $X^4+2X^2-7$.

I do know that $3$ stays prime in the ring of integers for the quadratic subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and that $3$ is not ramified in $O_K$.

I am a topologist working on my thesis, and any algebraic ideas on how to think about this question are welcome.

Comment: This is true if and only if $x^4 + 2x^2 - 7$ is irreducible $\bmod 3$. This is a finite computation.

Comment: Really? Can you explain why?

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's not obviously if and only if unless $\mathcal{O}_K$ is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^4 + 2x^2 - 7)$, but you should be fine if you know that $3$ doesn't ramify. The point is that $3$ is prime iff $\mathcal{O}_K/(3)$ is an integral domain iff it's a field, and (because you checked that $3$ doesn't ramify) we have $\mathcal{O}_K/(3) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(3, x^4 + 2x^2 - 7) \cong \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^4 + 2x^2 - 7)$.

Comment: [Here is an expository paper by Keith Conrad that should be useful.](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, your remark only applies if $3$ is co-prime to the index. The splitting field $K$ of $x^2 + 9$ is unramified at $3$, but $\mathcal{O}_K/(3) \ne \mathbf{F}_3[x]/x^2$. Alternatively, a stronger (but easier to check) condition is that $3$ is prime to the discriminant of the polynomial, which both implies that $3$ is unramified and $3$ is prime to the index.

Answer (score 4):

To use theorem 27 from Marcus's *Number Fields*, if we let $\alpha = \sqrt{2\sqrt{2} - 1}$ be a real root of $f(x) = x^4 + 2x^2 - 7$, you just need to check that 3 does not divide $|\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]|$, which can be accomplished by noting that $$\mathrm{disc}(1,...,\alpha^3) = |\mathcal{O}_K/\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]|^2 \mathrm{disc}(\mathcal{O}_K). $$ So it suffices to check that 3 does not divide the left hand side, which is equal to $$N^K_\mathbb{Q}(f'(\alpha)) = N^K_\mathbb{Q}(4\alpha(\alpha^2 + 1)),$$ which we can evaluate using multiplicativity and transitivity of the norm. It turns out this norm is just a power of 2 times 7, so we can use theorem 27. But $f$ has no roots $\bmod 3$, and one can check that it does not factor into quadratics $\bmod 3$. So 3 remains prime.